# VBA byte values write correctly to binary file but appear different when read back to userform

Tags: excel, vba, binary, endianness

I have a binary file that contains values in both 2-byte and 4-byte integers in big endian format. I can read the file and display the values on a user form fine.

```
Public Sub Binary_Header_To_Array()
    Application.StatusBar = "Reading Seg-Y File " & file_count & " of " & UBound(segyInFiles)

    Call SetBinaryHeaderByteFormat

    Open segyInFiles(CurrentFile) For Binary As #1

    z = 1

    For byte_count = 1 To UBound(BinaryHeader_byte_index)                'byte_count = number of fields in Seg-Y header
                    'Set pointer to byte index position
                    Seek #1, BinaryHeader_byte_index(byte_count)        'byte index is an array containing the number of fields in the Seg-Y header

                    Select Case BinaryHeader_byte_formats(byte_count)

                        Case 1 '16 bit integer (two's complement) / INTEGER
                            Call Byte_Formats.sixteen_bit_signed_integer
                            BinaryArray(byte_count, z) = integer_value 'CStr(integer_value)

                        Case 2 '32 bit integer (two's complement) / LONG
                            Call Byte_Formats.thirty_two_bit_signed_integer
                            BinaryArray(byte_count, z) = long_value 'CStr(long_value)

                    End Select

                Next byte_count

    Close #1
 End Sub

'**************************************************************

 Public Sub Binary_Header_To_UserForm()

    For i = 1 To UBound(BinaryHeader_byte_index)
        formMAIN.Controls("TextBox_BinHead_" & i).Text = BinaryArray(i, z)
    Next i

    formMAIN.TextBox_BinHead_35.Text = BinaryArray(35, 1) / 256

 End Sub

'**************************************************************

'Case 1 '16 bit integer (two's complement) / INTEGER
Public Sub sixteen_bit_signed_integer()
    Get #1, , read_two_bytes
    integer_value = (-Int(read_two_bytes(1) / 128) * 128 + (read_two_bytes(1) Mod 128)) * 256 + read_two_bytes(2)
    'out_string = out_string & Space(column_width - Len(CStr(integer_value))) & CStr(integer_value)
End Sub

'**************************************************************

'Case 2 '32 bit integer (two's complement) / LONG
Public Sub thirty_two_bit_signed_integer()
    Get #1, , read_four_bytes
    long_value = (-Int(read_four_bytes(1) / 128) * 128 + (read_four_bytes(1) Mod 128)) * 2 ^ 24 + read_four_bytes(2) * 2 ^ 16 _
    + read_four_bytes(3) * 2 ^ 8 + read_four_bytes(4)

    txtOutFileinput = OutFileDir & SegyFilename & "_InputBytes.txt"

' This prints the byte values to an ascii file as they are read
Open txtOutFileinput For Append As #6

    Print #6, long_value
    Print #6, "Byte1_" & read_four_bytes(1) & "_" & Seek(1)
    Print #6, "Byte2_" & read_four_bytes(2) & "_" & Seek(1)
    Print #6, "Byte3_" & read_four_bytes(3) & "_" & Seek(1)
    Print #6, "Byte4_" & read_four_bytes(4) & "_" & Seek(1)

    Close #6

    'out_string = out_string & Space(column_width - Len(CStr(integer_value))) & CStr(integer_value)
End Sub
```

I can then edit the values on the user form and write back to a new binary file (a copy of the original). The values are defined as Ineteger and Long vairables within  VBA, which would be written to file in little endian format.  As I want them to be stored as big endian, I have separated each value in to individual bytes and then I write the bytes to file in reverse order. At each step I export an ascii file with the byte index in the file and the corresponding byte value.

This all checks out the byte values are being written to the correct position in the file as I would expect for Big Endian.

The problem occurs when I read the newly created file back to display on the userform.  The 2-byte (Integer) values are displayed correctly but the 4-byte (Long) values have different numbers displayed.  My checking file that is created shows that the bytes have been ordered incorrectly.

As an example in the original file the value 13029 is stored as a 4-byte signed integer at position 3201-3204, teh individual byte values are;

```
Byte 1 = 0 (3201)
Byte 2 = 0 (3202)
Byte 3 = 50 (3203)
Byte 4 = 229 (3204)
```

When converting from Little Endian to Big Endian to write back to the file the value is written as:

```
Byte 4 = 0 (3201)
Byte 3 = 0 (3202)
Byte 2 = 50 (3203)
Byte 1 = 229 (3204)
```

I check this before using the 'put' statement and then again immediately afterwards I use the 'get' statement to return the value and print to an ascii file. The order is the same as above.

However, when I open  the file to read back into the userform the bytes have the values:

```
Byte 1 = 50 (3201)
Byte 2 = 229 (3202)
Byte 3 = 229 (3203)
Byte 4 = 0 (3204)
```

The indexing is correct eg 4 byte value at 3201 to 3204 just the byte values have been mixed up.

Can anybody help explain why this is happening or any further checks I can do to narrow down where the problem is occurring. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Rob

Comment: This may not be answerable without the IO code that reads and writes to the file. Is that something you can edit into the question?

Comment: Thanks, I'm away from my PC at the moment but will add in code later this evening.

Comment: In editing my question I had to go through my code to post the relevant bits and tidy up the comments.  Anyway, I found my first attempt (converting to hex values) hadn't been commented out.  So all the code was corrected, all the checking was correct and then right at the last minute it overwrites the correct values just before End Sub.  I commented this incorrect code out and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Re checked my code and found some old incorrect code was still present, after all the initial checks and writing to the file.  Commented this out and it works perfectly.